# Object.drawItself in PaintComponent doesnt work

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

PaintComponent doest paint figures. Just nothing is happening, clean Jframe appear.
**I think something is wrong with list or with the way i called method**
List is in class with Paint Component

```
public class Paint extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
     List<Figures> figuresList = new ArrayList<Figures>();
     Timer t = new Timer(5, this);

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (Figures figure : figuresList) {
        figure.drawItself(g, figure.getLocationX(), figure.getLocationY());
    }
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    {
        for (Figures figure : figuresList) {
            if (figure.getLocationX() < 0 || figure.getLocationX() > 540) {
                figure.setVelocityX(-figure.getVelocityX());
            }
            if (figure.getLocationY() < 0 || figure.getLocationX() > 220) {
                figure.setVelocityY(-figure.getVelocityY());
            }
            figure.setLocationX(figure.getLocationX()
                    + figure.getVelocityX());
            figure.setLocationY(figure.getLocationY()
                    + figure.getVelocityY());
        }
    }
    repaint();

}
```

And drawitself:

```
public class Circle implements Figures {    
    public int locationX = 12;
    public int locationY = 12;
    public int velocityX =1;
    public int velocityY =1;


    public void drawItself(Graphics g, int locationX, int locationY){
        this.locationX = locationX;
        this.locationY = locationY;
        g.drawOval(locationX, locationY, 40, 40);  
        g.fillOval(locationX, locationY, 40, 40);
    }
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Circle c = new Circle();
    Quadrat q = new Quadrat();
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.figuresList.add(c);
    p.figuresList.add(q);
    GUI.Configuration();


    }
```

GUI

```
public class GUI {


    public static void Configuration(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Figures Animation");
        frame.setSize(600,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new Paint();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Please explain a little more what you expected and what happened instead.

Comment: I expected form figures to appear on JFrame but nothing happend. No errors just clean JFrame.

Comment: When i coded this method as a constructor and wrote inside of PaintComponent method  " new Circle(g, 0,0)"  everything was fine but i need list of figures to ActionPerformed method and i need to call get set methods.

Comment: I'm having trouble accepting some of what you've said.  I think we need to see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: We definitely need to see your [mcve]. Also there appears to be no need for your passing `figure.getLocationX()` and `figure.getLocationY()`into the drawItself method since you're passing the figure's own state fields back into itself -- makes no sense. The figure already has those field values.

Comment: You've got some unusual code and perhaps should re-think it. I don't know what `t` is, but if it's a Timer or a Thread, it should not be started from within paintComponent. Likewise Circle should not be created there. This method is for painting and painting only and nothing else. You don't have control over whether or even if it is called, so get all program logic and state-altering code out of there.

Comment: You still need to create and post your  [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Did my edits help? I need Gets and Sets  because I have to monitor variables of figures in actionPerformed

Comment: Again, get that Timer out of your paintComponent method as it has no business being there. And while I see you creating JPanels, **I see no JFrame, I see nowhere where you add your Paint JPanel to a JFrame**. How can a JPanel draw anything if it's not even displayed? You can draw the Circle within paintComponent but create your Circle and start your Timer in the constructor.

Comment: I Added GUI code. I want to make animation of figures so i put timer there to keep calling actionPerformed method, is there any other way i can do that? I want figures to bounce from edges and from each others in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create and add a Paint instance here:

```
public class GUI {
    public static void Configuration(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Figures Animation");
        frame.setSize(600,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new Paint(); // *** new Paint is here, but nothing is added
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
    }
```

But nothing of use has been added to it. All the important stuff is added to a completely different Paint JPanel, one that is never displayed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Circle c = new Circle();
    Quadrat q = new Quadrat();
    Paint p = new Paint();  // **** ANOTHER new Paint is here, and it gets goodies
    p.figuresList.add(c);
    p.figuresList.add(q);

    // but is never added to a JFrame and is never displayed.

    GUI.Configuration();
}
```

Don't do this. Create **one** Paint JPanel, one only, add the important components to it, and then only add that one to the JFrame. Most important, don't just type in code, think and plan your program before committing it to code, and you won't see errors like this.

Also, and again, do not start a Timer from within paintComponent and don't create Circle there. You can draw your Circle instance in paintComponent, but create it and start your Timer within the Paint constructor.